# How can I find the toppest record in a table which represents hierarchies (in TSQL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy

Imagine a table like below:

**Table :** Person

**Fields:** ID,  FullName,  ParentID

Where ParentID references an ID in Person table again.

**Question:**
For the example given above, how can I query in TSQL to find the toppest Parent of the Person with ID = 7 ?

Comment: You probably want a [recursive query using a table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use common table expressions and do a recursive query until you find the topmost parent like so:

```
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 5 

CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT , ParentId INT)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1,0)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(2,1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(3,2);
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(4, 3);
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(5,4);

    WITH parent AS
    (
        SELECT id, parentId  from #tmp WHERE id = @id
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t.id, t.parentId FROM parent
        INNER JOIN #tmp t ON t.id =  parent.parentid
    )

    SELECT TOP 1 id FROM  parent
    order by id asc

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

if want to test that query it should be ok!

```
WITH  abcd
            AS (
                  -- anchor
                SELECT  id, FullName, ParentID,
                        FullName AS "Path"
                FROM    Person
                WHERE   ParentId IS NULL
                UNION ALL
                  --recursive member
                SELECT  p.id, p.FullName, p.ParentID,
                        CAST((a.path + '/' + p.FullName) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path"
                FROM    Person AS p
                        JOIN abcd AS a
                          ON p.ParentId = a.id
               )
    SELECT * FROM abcd
```